# AngularJS + es6 controller method and $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, controller, ecmascript-6

I try to use angularJS (1.6.6) and es6. And can't understand some feature.
I create controller:

```
export default class NodesController {
```

Create constructor

```
constructor(nodesService, $scope, $filter) {
```

And two variables:

```
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 10;
```

In constructor I wrote method:

```
$scope.numberOfPages = () => {console.log($scope)}
```

In view I try to use this method:

```
<span>{{currentPage + 1}} / {{numberOfPages()}}</span>
```

(it's simple pagination code)

I try to change pageSize in view:

```
<select ng-model="pageSize" class="form-control">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
```

And in console.log I get $scope with old pageSize. It doesn't change. 
If I use another construction:

```
$scope.paging = {currentPage: 1, pageSize: 20}
```

Everything is fine, I get new value in scope. Can somebody help to understand it?
And as additional question - Why numberOfPages() call 2 time when application init and when I change pageSize.

Comment: the difference is in using primitive type and object type, if you want to have two way binding, you should use objects, basically what is happening is that when we pass a primitive variable, its been passed by value and re-created, instead of been passed by reference. only objects are passed by reference.

Comment: why it's only when I use es6?

Comment: it does not have to be ES6, any two ways binding has to be done with objects. You have enough resources if you google two way binding primitive and objects :)

Comment: okey. I try to google it. But. I watched for this example https://codepen.io/khilnani/pen/qEWojX and there are no objects)

Comment: can you create a fiddle with full code, your approach seems to be different than the one you showed

Comment: The expression "{{currentPage + 1}} / {{numberOfPages()}}" should always return NaN due to $scope.numberOfPages method returns nothing but undefined. Is it?

Comment: @SushilBastola, I realy try to do fiddle. But I have some problem with it too. Can you help me? If you have enough time. https://codepen.io/Muskos/pen/oGNQYj I cant understand what does it mean: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: @dhilt yes it's true

Comment: it's hard to figure out from the incomplete code, but its pretty much sure that the problem is with the scope prototypal inheritance. for primitive to work for two ways binding, the binding in scope must be done in same level, it would be better to see your scope design since the code here does not tell much.(the code does not need to be working, you can show what you have done)

Comment: @SushilBastola https://codepen.io/Muskos/pen/oGNQYj I update code. I have three buttons, they change pageSize. I change pageSize in view. Then numberOfPages() run. And console.log always show pageSize=10.

Comment: @AlekseyMakas about the function being called twice, anything wrapped in double curly braces is an expression that gets evaluated at least once during the digest cycle. As it is function, it gets called first to get the value and next time to make sure that nothing has changed and to keep the view updated. About the another fiddle you sent, it works well because the scopes definition are in same level and i tried to console the scope too and it shows the correct value when i change the ng-model. There might be thing with your setting as the code still does not seem to be full

Comment: Okey. I understand why function beign called twice. I rewrite code with "this"  (without $scope) and everything is fine. I didn't understand why I got mistake. Magic) Thank you.